# VS Code with Typescript - Find where the performance issue is

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm working in a large NX (typescript) application that has some complex Types generated and various libraries.

I've noticed over time that VS Code is taking longer to display lint / error / type checking errors.

Is there a way to profile / debug in VS Code to get some sort of report / feedback to see where in the application it's taking time?

Comment: This might help: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/profiling

Comment: This looks more like a run time profile rather than during a build / type checking / linting.